# How come we can replace velocity with position in verlet integration?

Tags: integration, physics

I'm trying to learn verlet integration. I don't understand it very well to be honest. What I am having problem with is at the very beginning of it. I am reading the following, since I can't find it any simpler: https://www.gamedev.net/tutorials/programming/math-and-physics/a-verlet-based-approach-for-2d-game-physics-r2714/

What I am trying to understand is how exactly is it that velocity is represented with `position(now) - position(old)`. How does it equal the estimate of v(now)*timestep? How is this possible?

This might be a completely stupid question, because I completely failed physics back when I studied it. There might be something blatantly obvious about it, but I am looking for the mathematical proof behind it that I can understand with hopefully 'high school' maths.

Comment: Have you taken calculus? In particular, do you remember the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk no. I watched a video on it to see if I know it and I don't understand it. It's been... 6 years or more since I lost done anything to do with calculus but it also feels like.. I don't actually understand calculus like it was suppose to be understood. I done it automatically without understanding it.

Comment: Little precision (mathematics deserves precision...) : "Verlet" is the name of a person, not an object, therefore deserves a capital initial.

Comment: Your question could be formulated in this way : Why "(position(now) - position(old)) divided by time-step" is an estimate of v(now) ? Explanation : the quantity which is inside quotes signs is the slope distance divided by time (imagine a graphical representation : distance vs. time), which is (an estimation) of the (instantaneous) velocity. That's all...

Comment: Tbh, it will very hard to understand how any physics simulation works if you've mastered neither basic physics nor basic calculus. I highly recommend learning these subjects before you try to apply them in this way.